# Create a dictionary by filtering two lists with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I need a way to create a `Dictionary<key, value>` by filtering data from two lists using a linq statement. For example:

```
list1: { 1, 2, 3 }
list2: { <apple, 1>, <peach, 3> }
```

final dictionary should look like this: `{ <1, <apple, 1>>, <3, <peach, 3>> }`

`2` in list1 shall be skipped

Please any ideas how to solve this issue by using linq?

Comment: How would you do it without LINQ? That may help you get a Linq-based solution. Just give some own try.

Comment: list2 is already look like a dictionary :  <value -> apple , key -> 1>, I think you should provide more info for your models, probably they are more complicated...

Comment: @Soren its object with 2 properties i should have used (apple,1) instead of <>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `SelectMany` if you want:

```
var result = (from l1 in list1
              from l2 in list2
              where l1 == l2.Id
              select new 
              {
                  Id = l1,
                  Name = l2.Name
              }).ToDictionary(k=>k.Id, v=>v.Name);
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere this is a linq `query` syntax for `SelectMany`

Answer (score 6):

`Join` lists and put result into a dictionary

```
var d = list1.Join(list2, i=>i, o=>o.Id, (i,o)=>o)
             .ToDictionary(o=>o.Id);
```

try if with a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vDvk4C)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to merge two lists into one, and then [`Enumerable.ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate the dictionary.

Something like:

```
var result = list1.Zip(list2, (l, r) => Tuple.Create(l, r))
                  .ToDictionary(v => v.Item1, v => v.Item2);
```

Comment: what happens if list1 and lists don't have the same length as in question?

Comment: where is filter here?

Comment: @qxg It will stop at the end of the first list IT is not too hard to create a `ZipLong` that puts in a default element when the shorter list is exhausted.

Comment: @devhedgehog Question isn't really clear enough to be sure where to put it. Could do on the input lists before the `Zip` or on the output of the `Zip`.